# Entity Framework raw sql query not setting values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple query that I'm trying to execute:

```
sql = "SELECT DailyGamingID, GamingDate, LocationID FROM tblDailyGaming WHERE GamingDate >= '1/1/23' AND LocationID = 1";
List<TestData> testList = context.Database.SqlQuery<TestData> (sql).ToList ();
```

The query returns 10 rows.

I also have the following class:

```
public class TestData
{
    public int DailyGamingID;
    public DateTime GamingDate;
    public int LocationID;
}
```

testList will have the correct number of elements (10) in the list but none of the values of TestData have been set.  They are all default values.  Help please!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make those **properties** - not *fields* - in your class:

```
public class TestData
{
    public int DailyGamingID { get; set; };
    public DateTime GamingDate { get; set; };
    public int LocationID { get; set; };
}
```